# System.Web.HttpException: A page can have only one server-side Form tag

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have designed an aspx webpage that has no master page and only one Form tag in the page. The code below takes the webpage including all the controls and sends it as a email. The code works fine, I  receive the email however I get an error:

Server Error in '/' Application.

A page can have only one server-side Form tag.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: A page can have only one server-side Form tag.

```
        //code            
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        HtmlTextWriter tw = new HtmlTextWriter(new System.IO.StringWriter(sb));
        //Render the page to the new HtmlTextWriter which actually writes to the stringbuilder
        base.Render(tw);

        //Get the rendered content
        string sContent = sb.ToString();

        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;
        message.To.Add(new MailAddress("<receipient"));
        message.Subject = "Your order";

        message.From = new MailAddress("sender");
        message.Body = sContent; //this would be filled with the previous page
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp server");
        client.Send(message);
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the root cause of this error is Page.Render is called twice
the first time it the one you call manually in your code, and the second time is when it is got called automatically by the page life cycle.
After a little search , i found this post that hack the internals of page rendering to allow rendering twice

http://jberke.blogspot.com/2009/01/rendering-aspnet-page-twice.html

this example uses reflection to reset a flag that is set during the rendering process, all you need to do is to run the below code block after calling to base.Render()

```
System.Reflection.FieldInfo fi = typeof(Page).GetField("_fOnFormRenderCalled", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
if (fi != null)
{
    fi.SetValue(this, false);
}
```